# Add Woocommerce formatted product price to theme's product navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

Just installed Wordpress with BeTheme and Woocommerce in it and faced the following problem: when enter single product page there is Next-Prev buttons showing some info about next-prev product - name, date of upload, picture. Now I want to add price also but nothing found in StackOverflow works for me.

Here is my code, want to add the price instead of the date.

If need can provide the code of theme-shortcodes.php file.

Thank you in advance.

```
    if( is_object( $post ) ){
        // move this DOM element with JS
        $output .= '<a class="fixed-nav fixed-nav-'. $next_prev .' format-'. get_post_format( $post ) .'" href="'. get_permalink( $post ) .'">';

            $output .= '<span class="arrow"><i class="'. $icon .'"></i></span>';

            $output .= '<div class="photo">';
                $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'blog-navi' );
            $output .= '</div>';

            $output .= '<div class="desc">';
                $output .= '<h6>'. get_the_title( $post ) .'</h6>';
                $output .= '<span class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i>'. get_the_date(get_option('date_format'), $post->ID) .'</span>';
            $output .= '</div>';

        $output .= '</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a product object using the following function:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
```

And after that you will be able to access to all product's data. All available methods can be found [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html), but the ones you need are:

```
$regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
$sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
$price = $product->get_price();
```

and echo the price variable which price do you want to show.

Comment: Thank you, think that is. Problem is I'm not familiar with php so tried few times and the result was only broken page. May you show me example in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to **get the active formatted product price** form the `WC_Product` Object instance using [dedicated `get_price_html()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_price_html).

I have revisited a bit your code too:

```
if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && 'product' === get_post_type( $post ) ){
    global $product;

    if( ! is_a( $product, 'WP_Product' ) ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    }

    // move this DOM element with JS
    $output .= '<a class="fixed-nav fixed-nav-'. $next_prev .' format-'. get_post_format( $post ) .'" href="'. get_permalink( $post ) .'">
        <span class="arrow"><i class="'. $icon .'"></i></span>
        <div class="photo">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'blog-navi' ). '</div>
        <div class="desc">
            <h6>'. get_the_title( $post ) .'</h6>
            <span class="price">'. $product->get_price_html() .'</span>
        </div>  
    </a>';
}
```

Tested and works.